# Text box loses focus when DIV is hovered

Tags: javascript, events, gwt

I have a problem: When I enter a text into suggestion text box, popup panel appears.
But when user places mouse over this popup panel with suggestions - text box loses focus.

What should I do to prevent losing focus ?

Example which have the same behaviour: http://demo.raibledesigns.com/gwt-autocomplete/

Thanks for any help.

**Update 1**

`SuggestionMenu` which is being shown is extending `MenuBar` which sets focus for all menu items.

```
void itemOver(MenuItem item, boolean focus) {
    if (item == null) {
      // Don't clear selection if the currently selected item's menu is showing.
      if ((selectedItem != null)
          && (shownChildMenu == selectedItem.getSubMenu())) {
        return;
      }
    }

    // Style the item selected when the mouse enters.
    selectItem(item);
    if (focus) {
      focus();
    }

    // If child menus are being shown, or this menu is itself
    // a child menu, automatically show an item's child menu
    // when the mouse enters.
    if (item != null) {
      if ((shownChildMenu != null) || (parentMenu != null) || autoOpen) {
        doItemAction(item, false);
      }
    }
  }
```

It's clear that i cant fix loosing focus. Now question is - how to make on pressing backspace or any key to focus on edit box?

Thanks in advance

Comment: my best guess is that onmouseover .focus() is called on the list item... so that the keyboard navigation works...

Comment: Can you not just explicitly make a call after the user has made their suggest selection to focus() on the text box once again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I have used GWT 1.7.0. - and it's has focus() call in it's source code.

This problem can be solved by updating to GWT v2.

Thanks markovuksanovic for help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is your code? Or is this a snippet from gwt source?

My guess is that this is your custom code... In that case you shouldn't focus the element to style it but instead attach a handler... sth like

```
public HandlerRegistration addMouseOutHandler(MouseOutHandler handler) {
  return this.addDomHandler(handler, MouseOutEvent.getType());
}
public HandlerRegistration addMouseOverHandler(MouseOverHandler handler) {
  return this.addDomHandler(handler, MouseOverEvent.getType());
}


element.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
  public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
    element.removeStyleName(HEADER_STYLE_HOVERING);
  }
});

element.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
  public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
    element.addStyleName(HEADER_STYLE_HOVERING);
  }

});
```

just replace the *element* with whatever you want to attach the handlers to.

Does this help you?

Comment: I have checked the showcase example and the SuggestBox is not loosing focus when placing mouse over an item.

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwSuggestBox

Could you give some more information on how you're using this suggetBox widget?